# Web crawlers and non-ASCII characters in sitemap.xml

Tags: seo, web-crawler

One of our sites has non-ASCII (non-english) characters in URLs:

```
http://example.com/kb/начало-работы/оплата
```

I wonder how do web crawlers (particularly Googlebot) handle these situations? Do these URLs have to be encoded or otherwise processed?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is best url-encoded. This is the standard.